# How to Get Resolution image, in android from php

Tags: php, android

i want get width and height from config.php in my server, 
i confused this problem...

This is "Code Android task"

```
public class task_list_todo extends DroidGap {
private navigasi_uuy mc;
public static String current_form = ""; 
private String userid = "";
private String root_url = "";
public static String last_barcode="";
public static String task_type = "";
public static String data_task = "";

public static String latlong ="";
public static String cellid="";
public static String gps_time="";
public static String gps_criteria="";
public static Boolean must_get_location = false;
private static Boolean dapet_gps = false;

public static String asal_form = "";
public static String nama_folder = "";
public String taskid = "";
public String barc = "";
public String remark = "";
public String halaman = "12121212";
public static String photo_id = "";
public static String id_task  = "";
public static String atf_barc  = "";
public static String type_task  = "";

public static String id_tombol = "";

public boolean barcodenya = false;

private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 13731;
private static final int CAMERA_REQ = 13732;
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

This is code, i want dynamic from config.php

```
public static int output_width=480;
public static int output_height=320;
```

and this is config.php

```
$uploaded_image_width_height= "640x480";
```

I want dynamic, width and height from config.php

Answer (score 0):

Print out the value of variable in PHP and then make HTTP requst to that file whenever you want to update variable in Java.